# Show integer values instead of decimal in MPAndroidChart by PhilJay?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, integer, mpandroidchart

I'm using `MPAndroidChart` for showing hours of work by day.

Everything is working fine, but I can't figure out how to show integer, not float. For example, if I insert 19 hours in chart, it's showing like this at the top of each chart. Can I show it like 19 h?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set value Formatter

```
val xAxis = barChart.xAxis
xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis -> value.roundToInt() }
```

Comment: barDataSet.setValueFormatter { value, entry, dataSetIndex, viewPortHandler -> value.roundToInt().toString() }

Answer (score 6):

Set value formatter, If you set 0 in DefaultValueFormatter it will be shown like integer value example 25, if you set 1 now the output will be 25.0

```
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "")

barDataSet.valueFormatter = DefaultValueFormatter(0)
```

Comment: simple and easy. Best aswer